# How exactly work the this keyword declared into a function defined inside an object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am pretty new in OO paradigm in JavaScript language (I came from Java) and I have the following doubt related to the correct meaning of **this** param in this specific case.

I have the following code:

```
var obj = {

    fn:function(a,b) {
        log(this-);
    }

}
```

Ok, from what I have understand (correct me if I am doing wrong assertion) the previous code define an **ob** object that contain a fnction named **fn**.

First doubt: doing in this way am I creating an instance of this object (creating in memory) or am I only declaring it (as a Java class)?

I think that I am creating in memory a specific instance of this object but I am not sure of this...

Ok, then doing:

```
obj.fn(3,4);
```

here the **this** value is the identification of the specific **obj** object (the instance) on which I am calling the **fn()** function.

Is it my reasoning correct or am I missing something?

And what happens if I don't declare the **fn()** function into an object definition? What happens if I put it dirctly into a .js file? Is **this** keyword refred to the global object?

Comment: I think that you are correct.

Comment: If `fn` is not declared in an object, I believe `this` is related to the function that owns the code, so `fn` is this. If it was not in a function, `this` would refer to the `window` global, if it's there.

Comment: It does not matter where you declare the function with the `this` keyword, it matters that you call it on `obj` in `obj.fn(…)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 2):

First doubt : Yes, you are creating an object in memory

There are **at least** 3 rules that I know of for determining the value of the *this* keyword and all of them are determined based on the callsite where a function is invoked.

1) Default binding : By default, *this* binds to the global object.

```
var a = 10; // declared in global scope

function foo(){
 console.log(this.a); // 10
}

foo(); // callsite
```

2) Implicit binding : *this* binds to the object whose method is invoked

```
var a = 10; // global

var obj = {
  a : 20,
  foo : function(){
         console.log(this.a); // 20
        }
  }

obj.foo(); // callsite
```

3) Explicit binding : *this* binds to whatever object you specify.
   There are 2 ways to do this, call() and apply()

```
var a = 10;

var obj = {
   a : 20
};

function foo(){
   console.log(this.a); // 20
};

foo.call(obj); // bind to obj
```

Comment: there is one more rule - using the new keyword before a function call.

Comment: There are much [more than 3 rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), you are for example forgetting `new`. Also, `foo()` does *not* bind `this` to the global object, it does bind it to `undefined` - only sloppy mode functions default that to the global object.

Comment: When working with Javascript functions this refers the current object, which depends on the context of the function.  http://www.coding-dude.com/wp/web-design/javascript/javascript-functions-this-that-the-other/

Comment: `at least` spelling